# SQL Query - Similar queries, big difference in execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, execution-time

A certificate (or survey) is assigned to a bunch of facilities spanned across different areas and districts (an area contains multiple districts). These facilities are supposed to respond to the surveys and their responses are recorded in the database, using ResponseDate (normally null until they respond).

I am trying to get a count of response within an area and also within a district. The queries is almost identical, but one that spans more facilities (i.e By Area) is executed instantaneously and the other, by district, takes 104 seconds! I have checked the tables to see if there is any difference between AREA and DISTRICT tables and did not find anything; spent most of the day and can't figure out what is wrong.

```
Table FACILITYDATA: FACID, AREAID, DISTRICTID.
Table AREA: AREAID, AREA
Table DISTRCIT: DISTRICTID, AREAID, DISTRICT
Table FACILITYCERTIFICATE: FACCERTIFICATEID, FACID, CERTITEMID
Table FACILITYCOMPLICANCE: FACCERTIFICATEID, RESPONSEDATE

-- National, by Area (almost instant result)

select a.Area, sum(case when fcom.ResponseDate is not null then 1 else 0 end) Cnt_Certified 
from FacilityCertificate fc 
inner join FacilityData fd on fd.FacID = fc.FacilityID 
inner join Area a on a.AreaID = fd.AreaID 
left join FacilityCompliance fcom on fcom.FacCertificateID = fc.FacCertificateID 
where fc.CertItemID = 1 
group by a.Area 
order by a.Area;

-- by District, within given Area -- Takes 104 seconds
select d.District, sum(case when fcom.ResponseDate is not null then 1 else 0 end) Cnt_Certified 
from FacilityCertificate fc 
inner join FacilityData fd on fd.FacID = fc.FacilityID 
inner join District d on d.DistrictID = fd.DistrictID
left join FacilityCompliance fcom on fcom.FacCertificateID = fc.FacCertificateID 
where fc.CertItemID = 1 and fd.AreaID = 4
group by d.District 
order by d.District;
```

i am not sure if this info suffices or sample data would be needed.

Comment: It could be many things.  Size of data in the different tables?  Or more likely one has an index and the other does not.  The area table or FacilityCertificate table may have index on AreaID (one or both) but the FacilityCertfiicate or District may not have an index on DistructID  NOTE:  Adding an index may fix this scenario but you do not want to just randomly add indexes, you will want to examine your DB first, but in this case it looks like you would especially since it is an ID

Comment: What datatypes are the two columns? Does Area have an index built on it, whereas, district does not?

Comment: It's quite plausibly an Index vs No-Index on the different Joins. Also, what tool might you be using to run through the SQL?

Comment: it is the same data, I am just trying to group them differently (by Area or by District). How do I check in SSMS if the tables you mentioned have indexes? When I select Area and District tables, I see "indexable:true" and "(is full-text indexed: no)".

Comment: columns AREAID and DISTRICTID in FACILITYDATA table are foreign keys, pointing to AREAID in AREA table and DISTRICTID in DISTRICT table.

Comment: when I expand the tables and check "indexes" for all three tables (area, district, facilitydata), I see something like "PK__Area__70B8202847DBAE45"

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but once I changed the indexing in "DISTRICT" table from Clustered to Non-Clustered, the query executed in 0 seconds instead of 104 seconds.

I was reading up on indexes and how they are set up and articles showed using non-clustered option when setting one up and all my indexes, which I did not create but I think were created when I set up a column as primary key, were marked as Clustered.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this but it seems this change has resolved my issue. Thanks to all the people who mentioned the issue could be related to index.